# Should I assign a function that takes arguments to function pointers that take a void?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm currently reading a beginner book about embedded systems "Making embedded Systems - design patterns for great software". In the testing section they say its a good idea to have a terminal interface to your embedded system, with a set of commands you can call, to test certain things in your system.

The way they suggest implementing these commands is by having an array of c structures comprised of a function pointer and a const char *. Then initialise your command array with your command names and respective functions you want to be called by that command.

You have the user select type a string, that string then gets compared to the char * in your command array and if it matches a particular entry call the corresponding function in the structure.

Here's the example code.

```
typedef void(*functionPointerType)(void);

struct commandStruct
{
    char const *name;
    functionPointerType execute;
    char const *help
};

const struct commandStruct commands[] = {
        {"ver", &CmdVersion, "Display firmware version"},
        {"flashTest" &CmdFlashTest, "Runs the flash unit test"}
};
```

I understand this fine. What I don't understand is the throw away comment afterwards which says, if one wanted to pass arguments to the functions having one would parse them from the command string and pass them to the function defined by the function pointer.

I was at first confused because I didn't think that C would allow me to assign a function which takes an argument to a function pointer that expects void, but I tried it and I can my it compiles and runs. The compiler does give me warnings though.

I guess my question is this: Is this a perfectly valid thing to do or is it a bit of a "hack"? Will certain compilers not allow me to do this?

Comment: Usually you have a `NULL` pointer at the end of that array for one or more of those fields so you don't walk off the end and into invalid memory. This one requires having a separate length counter constant, which can fall out of sync.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, you're not assigning a function to a function pointer, but a pointer to a function to an object that holds a pointer to a function. And you don't need an `&` either, a function name decays to a pointer to a function almost everywhere:

```
const struct commandStruct commands[] = {
        {"ver", (functionPointerType)CmdVersion, "Display firmware version"},
        {"flashTest" (functionPointerType)CmdFlashTest, "Runs the flash unit test"}
};
```

This should silence the warnings, though some newer versions of GCC have gotten some really annoying warnings that will be enabled with `-Wall` that will complain about this perfectly valid construct.

Note that when you *call* the function via this pointer, you *must* cast it back to the original prototype, otherwise the behaviour will be undefined.

Therefore if you want to pass in arguments, you'd better change `functionPointerType` so that it matches the prototype of both `CmdVersion` and `CmdFlashTest`; as an added bonus you'd not need to have those explicit casts any more.

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is that probably some commands have arguments, some do not, so there is no single function type that fits all. That's probably the reason `void(*)(void)` is chosen for the struct.

Answer (score 2):

Two function types are not "compatible" with each other if their return types differ.  If both are declared with prototypes, then they also are not compatible if they take different numbers of arguments or if any of the pairs of corresponding arguments fail to have compatible types.

It is allowed to *convert* between pointers to incompatible function types, and some compilers might even perform such conversions automatically, without a warning, though that would constitute an extension.  But you elicit undefined behavior if you call a function via a pointer to a function type incompatible with the function's actual type, or if you pass arguments that (after argument promotions and conversions, as applicable), are not compatible with the function's declared parameter types.

Thus, your book's throwaway comment at best falls a bit short.

If you want to provide a terminal interface that allows commands to take arguments then there are a couple of different ways to approach it, but my first suggestion would be to emulate the signature expected for `main()` in a hosted environment.  That is, declare the handler functions with this signature, instead:

```
typedef void(*functionPointerType)(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

There might be reason to assert varying kinds of `const`ness on `argv`.  That puts fairly minimal parsing requirements on the front end of the terminal interface, while giving all your handler functions a consistent signature that can accommodate arguments.

Comment: This way at least if someone calls a function with the wrong number of arguments, it will be a runtime error rather than undefined behaviour. The book is falling *way* short if it's suggesting the user simply cast un-wrapped functions and store those, rather than calling them from a wrapper with a single common type.

Comment: Thank you your answer has been helpful, however I didn't quite fully follow the bit from "But you elicit undefined behavior..  function's declared parameter types. " Here what is the function's "actual type"? The function pointers type?

So if the function pointer took a char and you made that function pointer point to a function which took a float, it then wouldn't work? But if you had a function pointer that took an double and passed it a function that took float it would work? How come it works with a function that takes void?

Comment: @genericpurpleturtle, A function's actual type is the one established by its definition, where the function body also appears.  *That* is what ultimately establishes how you must call the function.  If you try to call it via a function pointer that misrepresents the function's argument or return types, then the behavior is undefined.  Note, too, that the applicable definition of "compatible" here *does not* comprising passing a `double` where a `float` is expected, or vise versa, when the actual function definition contains a prototype.

Answer (score 2):

It is poor advice. Here's how it is done in practice.

Define your callback functions similar to `main()`, i.e. taking the number of strings, and the strings, as arguments: `int callback(int argc, char *argv[])`.

So, your command list could be e.g.

```
static const struct {
    const char *name;
    const char *help;
    int       (*func)(int argc, char *argv[]);
} firmware_cmd[] = {
    { "help",      "help [ command ]", help_func },
    { "ver",       "ver",              display_version },
    { "flashtest", "flashtest",        flash_text },
    { 0 }
};
```

In the firmware command parser/lexer, define some specific callback function return values:

```
enum {
    FIRMWARE_CMD_OK = 0,
    FIRMWARE_CMD_ARGS,   /* Invalid arguments! */
    FIRMWARE_CMD_HELP,   /* Command help asked */
    /* All others are error/failure codes */
};
```

Now, when the command parser/lexer calls the function, it outputs additional text depending on the return value:

- `FIRMWARE_CMD_OK`: "OK"
- `FIRMWARE_CMD_ARGS`: "Invalid arguments. Run 'help COMMAND' to see help, or 'help' to see full command list."
- `FIRMWARE_CMD_HELP`: the `->help` text.
- All other return values: `Error (returnvalue)`

This should allow simple, but versatile firmware command functions, with additional detail (in the error number) if an error fails.

Answer (score 1):

> if one wanted to pass arguments to the functions [...] one would parse them from the command string and pass them to the function defined by the function pointer

This means *you would change the function pointer type to one taking arguments*, **not** *you would assign a function of a different type* to the pointer.

Eg.

```
typedef void (*functionType)(int argc, const char *argv[]);
```

> I was at first confused because I didn't think that C would allow me to assign a function which takes an argument to a function pointer that expects void, but I tried it and I can my it compiles and runs. The compiler does give me warnings though.

If your program doesn't compile with `-Wall -Werror` (for GCC-style options, at least), it probably isn't correct.

Compiling with warnings just means the compiler kept going as best it could - C compilers generally lets you do things that aren't strictly legal, on the grounds that you *might* know better.

> Is this a perfectly valid thing to do ... ?

No. It's a hack that could work correctly in certain - different - circumstances. Specifically, if you cast the function pointer back to the right type (matching the function prototype) before calling, it will probably work. This only makes sense if you somehow know (or record) what the correct type is.

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not allow this, as the types are not compatible.

For a function to match the type of a function pointer, number and types of the arguments, as well as the return type, have to match.  Otherwise, the function will not be called correctly and you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When you have a set of functions that can be called through a function pointer, all of those functions need to have the same signature.  One way to do this is to have all such functions accept a single parameter of type `void *`, similarly to functions that start a thread.  That way you can use a struct to contain all the arguments in question and pass its address to the function, then the function would cast the `void *` back to the expected type.

Comment: ... or you need to have a dispatching mechanism that can branch to the proper cast...